# How to override DNS resolver ordering while connected to L2TP VPN

Tags: network, vpn, dns

OS: `macOS Mojave 10.14 (18A389)`

Current network setup:

- Local domain: `home.rossipedia.com`
- Subnet: `172.16.10.0/24`
- Gateway / DHCP server / DNS server: `172.16.10.1`

Output of `scutil --dns`:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.rossipedia.com
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.10.1
  if_index : 21 (en8)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

... (mdns common stuff)...

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.rossipedia.com
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.10.1
  if_index : 21 (en8)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

This works fine. I can find `*.home.rossipedia.com` hosts without issue.

However, the moment I connect to a L2TP VPN, my system gets reconfigured to use the *VPN* DNS servers to resolve hosts on my *home* search domain.

```
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.rossipedia.com
  nameserver[0] : x.x.x.x  <- VPN DNS SERVER 1
  nameserver[1] : x.x.x.x  <- VPN DNS SERVER 2
  if_index : 23 (ppp0)
  flags    : Supplemental, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000003 (Reachable,Transient Connection)
  order    : 100000

resolver #2
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.10.1
  if_index : 21 (en8)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
  order    : 200000

... (mdns common stuff)...
```

The scoped queries configuration looks right, though:

```
DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.rossipedia.com
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.10.1
  if_index : 21 (en8)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : first.vpn.domain
  search domain[1] : second.vpn.domain
  nameserver[0] : x.x.x.x
  nameserver[1] : x.x.x.x
  if_index : 23 (ppp0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000003 (Reachable,Transient Connection)
```

In my Network System Preferences, I have the VPN connection last in the Service Order dialog. If I move the VPN connection to *before* my ethernet connection, then my local DNS server doesn't show up in the resolver list *at all* (while connected to the VPN):

```
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : first.vpn.domain
  search domain[1] : second.vpn.domain
  nameserver[0] : x.x.x.x
  nameserver[1] : x.x.x.x
  if_index : 23 (ppp0)
  flags    : Supplemental, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000003 (Reachable,Transient Connection)
  order    : 100000

resolver #2
  nameserver[0] : x.x.x.x <- these are the same as above
  nameserver[1] : x.x.x.x
  if_index : 23 (ppp0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000003 (Reachable,Transient Connection)
  order    : 200000

... (mdns common stuff)...
```

#### What I want:

Ideally, what I'd like to see when connection to a VPN is something like:

```
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.rossipedia.com
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.10.1
  if_index : 21 (en8)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : first.vpn.domain
  search domain[1] : second.vpn.domain
  nameserver[0] : x.x.x.x
  nameserver[1] : x.x.x.x
  if_index : 23 (ppp0)
  flags    : Supplemental, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000003 (Reachable,Transient Connection)
  order    : 100000

  ... (mdns common stuff)...
```

This way I could resolve all `*.home.rossipedia.com` hosts via my local DNS server at `172.16.10.1`, and any hosts on my VPN domain would be resolved using the VPN DNS servers.

I've tried changing the order of services in the Network pref pane, changing the local domain on the DNS/DHCP server, deleting and re-creating the VPN connection, nothing has worked so far.

Is this possible? Or am I misunderstanding how this all works?

Answer (score 0):

My case was very similar. This worked:

1. Ordered VPN connection first in Service Order dialog -- which removes local DNS server, as you noted;
2. Created additional resolver for local lan:

   ```
   % sudo mkdir /etc/resolver
   % echo "nameserver 172.16.10.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolver/home.rossipedia.com
   ```

After that, both local and remote hosts became accessible via FQDN, such as `host.first.vpn.domain` and `other.home.rossipedia.com`.